# Create Dataframe w/All Combinations of 2 Categorical Columns then Sum 3rd Column by Each Combination

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tibble

I have an large messy dataset but want to accomplish a straightforward thing.  Essentially I want to fill a tibble based on every combination of two columns and sum a third column.

As a hypothetical example, say each observation has the company_name (Wendys, BK, McDonalds), the food_option (burgers, fries, frosty), and the total_spending (in $). I would like to make a 9x3 tibble with the company, food, and total as a sum of every observation. Here's my code so far:

```
df_table <- df %>% 
      group_by(company_name, food_option) %>%
      summarize(total= sum(total_spending))
```

```
 company_name                food_option               total
   <chr>                     <chr>                      <dbl>
 1 Wendys                    Burgers                   757
 2 Wendys                    Fries                     140
 3 Wendys                    Frosty                    98
 4 McDonalds                 Burgers                   1044
 5 McDonalds                 Fries                     148
 6 BK                        Burgers                   669
 7 BK                        Fries                     38
```

The problem is that McDonalds has zero observations with "Frosty" as the food_option.  Consequently, I get a partial table. I'd like to fill that with a row that shows:

```
 8  McDonalds      Frosty   0 
 9  BK             Frosty   0
```

I know I can add the rows manually, but the actual dataset has over a hundred combinations so it will be tedious and complicated. Also, I'm constantly modifying the upstream data and I want the code to automatically fill correctly.

Thank you SO MUCH to anyone who can help. This forum has really been a godsend, really appreciate all of you.

Comment: Try using this at the end `... %>% complete(company_name, food_option, fill=list(total = 0))`. This is a `tidyr` function.

Comment: Yes I went that route and for some reason it still returns the exact same table.  I think it may be because R isn't sure what to fill?

Comment: For me it works fine for the example you posted. If it didn't know what to fill you'd just have NA values for the combinations that don't exist. So the issue must be coming from somewhere else. I'll post an answer below so you can check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(food_option = factor(food_option, levels = unique(food_option))) %>% 
  group_by(company_name, food_option, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(total_spending))
```

Newer versions of `dplyr` have a `.drop` argument to `group_by` where if you've got a factor with pre-defined levels they will not be dropped (and you'll get the zeros).

Answer (score 0):

You can use tidyr::expand_grid():

```
tidyr::expand_grid(company_name = c("Wendys", "McDonalds", "BK"), 
                   food_option = c("Burgers", "Fries", "Frosty"))
```

to create all possible variations

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

# example data
df = read.table(text = "
company_name                food_option               total
1 Wendys                    Burgers                   757
2 Wendys                    Fries                     140
3 Wendys                    Frosty                    98
4 McDonalds                 Burgers                   1044
5 McDonalds                 Fries                     148
6 BK                        Burgers                   669
7 BK                        Fries                     38
", header=T)

df %>% complete(company_name, food_option, fill=list(total = 0))

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   company_name food_option total
#   <fct>        <fct>       <dbl>
# 1 BK           Burgers       669
# 2 BK           Fries          38
# 3 BK           Frosty          0
# 4 McDonalds    Burgers      1044
# 5 McDonalds    Fries         148
# 6 McDonalds    Frosty          0
# 7 Wendys       Burgers       757
# 8 Wendys       Fries         140
# 9 Wendys       Frosty         98
```